# Passing multiple arguments to bash

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I have a script that launches certain nodes based on what arguments you enter

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        if [ "$2" == "puppet" ]; then
           set_puppet_variables
           check_ES_reqs
           start
        elif [ "$2" == "puppet1" ]; then
           set_puppet1_variables
           check_ES_reqs
           start
        elif [ "$2" == "master" ]; then
           set_master_variables
           check_ES_reqs
           start
        fi
        if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
             set_puppet_variables
             check_ES_reqs
             start
             set_master_variables
             check_ES_reqs
             start
         fi
```

I want to be able to launch multiple specific nodes for example when I type in **command service ES start puppet puppet1** it will then launch only those two nodes.

Is there a way to format the `$2` in my logic to accept `$3`, `$4` depending on how many nodes I add? as there will be more. Like making the `$2` to a `$2*` to accept the second argument and any others so I can launch multiple specific nodes.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: You could loop through the puppet options with the bash `shift` command.  There's a lot of replicated operation in each of those *if*s.

Comment: FYI it is acceptable to have a case inside another case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift `$1` out of the argument list, then loop over the remaining arguments.

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        shift
        while [ $# -ne 0 ]
        do
            case "$1" in 
                puppet)
                    ... ;;
                puppet1)
                    ... ;;
                master)
                    ... ;;
                "")
                    ... ;;
            esac
            shift
        done ;;
```

Answer (score 2):

`shift` off your command, work on the rest.  This is more or less what I'm expecting you require:

```
cmd="$1"
shift; # get rid of it.
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  # if there are no parameters, use puppet and master
  set -- puppet master
fi

case "$cmd" in
  start)
    for node in "$@"
    do
      set_variables "$node" # slight rename here, make it easier to reuse
      check_ES_reqs
      start
    done
    ;;
  # ...
esac
```